# I want to make a P2P networked (thinking about using mirror) game with unity, with no dedicated server, similar to Terraria and Valheim

Tags: unity-game-engine, unity3d-mirror

I have managed to basically connect with my friend over internet, by forwarding my IP address from my router settings... this is not viable because there are few people willing to do what I did to play games with their friends. So how to actually do UDP hole punching (basically what I did manually to my router) in unity using the mirror networking solution...

Comment: You cant punch holes routers from a game without having full access to the router and likely its api.

Comment: Than is it impossible?

Comment: Well it possibly is. But it is far beyond SO and its not necessarily a limitation of unity but the fact you woukd have to open a port on the router and a number of routers dont even let you with the access given to customers so its far beyond an SO question

Comment: this thread might help https://forum.unity.com/threads/mlapi-puncher-nat-punchthrough.708320/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Photon Bolt or Photon Fusion to let players host a game on their local machine like minecraft, etc. Photon provides relay as well as tries to use STUN to establish direct peer to peer connection to the host via UDP. PUN2 is also a good choice, although I like Photon Bolt/Fusion better - it's less of a simple RPC framework and more programmer oriented. Also, PUN does not do any STUN direct peer connection, it will always be relayed. Photon Bolt and Fusion will first attempt a STUN direct peer connection and then fallback to relay if necessary. It's been around for years and is the best choice.

Sure you can develop a Unity game with Mirror (although without a relay built in) but it's not nearly as easy to setup and use as Photon Bolt/Fusion and they don't provide a relay. As someone mentioned, you might be able to hack something together in some way but yeah - not recommended.

Ugh, yeah don't use WebRTC for a Unity game (or probably anything other than streaming music/video like it was made for to be honest).

Unity's MLAPI is "under development" and their last API was suddenly dropped "deprecated", so I wouldn't use that.

Comment: It may be a noob question, but I don't have to pay for some service right? They are just using the relay to connect to other players? In other words the cc0 of 20 limit is still used in this case?

Comment: @Michael would love to hear the reasons for your reservations about WebRTC. Data channels are a part of the original spec.

Comment: @PeterHayman all the SDKs include easy ways to hook up Unity objects/paradigms and in Bolt's case even the Animator Controller.. as well as easy programmatic hooks for things, so you aren't sending/receiving chunks of data and the handling of it.

Comment: Photon Bolt and Photon PUN have a free tier. I also recommend you look at adding PlayFab to your multiplayer game, which looks daunting but is actually only a few lines of code for basic integration and gives you user authentication and the ability to store user associated data easily as well as user metrics and a nice web UI to view/modify it all. I think most game should have some kind of PlayFab integration (there are other providers like Xsolla but not as easy to use as Playfab's SDK). Once your game exceeds the free tier, you should be able to pay the monthly costs.

Comment: @BogdanMocanu you can read their pricing and email them questions about it, but it's a flat fee then becomes a monthly fee as CCU continues to go up. If your game becomes popular, you would need to pay fees and find a way to recoup those fees and become profitable etc if that's your goal or just pay for it like a hobby or something.

Answer (score 2):

A common solution to this problem is WebRTC, which takes care of the hole punching under the hood. Unity maintains [this package](https://github.com/Unity-Technologies/com.unity.webrtc) which implements WebRTC. They also provide a great [tutorial](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.webrtc@2.0/manual/en/tutorial.html) on how to use it. The nuts and bolts of it are:

```cs
using UnityEngine;
using Unity.WebRTC;

public class MyPlayerScript : MonoBehaviour
{

    RTCPeerConnection localConnection, remoteConnection;
    RTCDataChannel sendChannel, receiveChannel;

    private void Awake()
    {
        // Initialize WebRTC
        WebRTC.Initialize();
        // Create local peer
        localConnection = new RTCPeerConnection();
        sendChannel = localConnection.CreateDataChannel("sendChannel");
        channel.OnOpen = handleSendChannelStatusChange;
        channel.OnClose = handleSendChannelStatusChange;
        // Create remote peer
        remoteConnection = new RTCPeerConnection();
        remoteConnection.OnDataChannel = ReceiveChannelCallback;
        // register comms paths
        localConnection.OnIceCandidate = e => { 
            !string.IsNullOrEmpty(e.candidate)
            || remoteConnection.AddIceCandidate(ref e); 
        }
        remoteConnection.OnIceCandidate = e => { 
            !string.IsNullOrEmpty(e.candidate)
            || localConnection.AddIceCandidate(ref e); 
        }
        localConnection.OnIceConnectionChange = state => {
            Debug.Log(state);
        }
    }

    //handle begin
    IEnumerator Call(){
        var op1 = localConnection.CreateOffer();
        yield return op1;
        var op2 = localConnection.SetLocalDescription(ref op1.desc);
        yield return op2;
        var op3 = remoteConnection.SetRemoteDescription(ref op1.desc);
        yield return op3;
        var op4 = remoteConnection.CreateAnswer();
        yield return op4;
        var op5 = remoteConnection.setLocalDescription(op4.desc);
        yield return op5;
        var op6 = localConnection.setRemoteDescription(op4.desc);
        yield return op6;
    }

    //handle send messages
    void SendMessage(string message)
    {
        sendChannel.Send(message);
    }

    void SendBinary(byte[] bytes)
    {
        sendChannel.Send(bytes);
    }

    //handle receive messages
    void ReceiveChannelCallback(RTCDataChannel channel) 
    {
        receiveChannel = channel;
        receiveChannel.OnMessage = HandleReceiveMessage;  
    }
    void HandleReceiveMessage(byte[] bytes)
    {
        var message = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bytes);
        Debug.Log(message);
    }

    //handle end
    private void OnDestroy()
    {
        sendChannel.Close();
        receiveChannel.Close();

        localConnection.Close();
        remoteConnection.Close();

        WebRTC.Finalize();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

I have also found a useful way to do this using [mirror](https://github.com/vis2k/Mirror) and the epic free relay for [this](https://github.com/FakeByte/EpicOnlineTransport). Thanks so much for the other answers, it really helped understand better what I needed to search and use!